# Configuring Notepad++ for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a  newbie to ruby on rails and programming in general. I would like to use notepad++.
I have it installed but I can't figure out how to enable syntax highlighting. I have searched through Google but I've only found how to fix erb files (Apparently there is an error with these file type).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Go into Settings > Style Configurator and select your language (Ruby):

[image: Style configurator in Notepad++]

In the box labelled "User ext." in the bottom-left-hand corner, add the extensions that you'd like to be highlighted as Ruby, separated by a space. Then just Save & Close.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the "language" tab, go down to 'R' and then go to "Ruby" this will also enable syntax highlighting but only for the duration of your session.